# Array rearrange. All lesser than a on the left of a. All greater than a on the right of a

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I’d like to rearrange my array **A** so that all elements greater than some arbitrary number  **a** from the list are on the right of **a**, and all elements lesser than **a** will be on the left of **a**.

Example

```
A = [4,5,1,2]
a = A[0] #4

Output:

[1,2,4,5]
or
[2,1,4,5]
```

I was trying to go from left and right finding the number >= **a** and <= **a** respectively. Once found I would switch those numbers.

Comment: This is called partitioning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Comment: I’am just curious what flaw this question have that it was downvoted. Problem was clearly described, and example was provided. It’s not even a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a python function which give you output as expected you are

```
# here A is list, and a is A[x]
def arrangeit(A, a):
    finalLst = [a]
    for i in A:
        if(i < a):
            finalLst = [i] + finalLst
        if(i > a):
            finalLst.append(i)

    return finalLst

A = [4,5,1,2]
a = A[0] #4

print(arrangeit(A, a))
```

Comment: The solution is correct and clear, but can you do this in O(1) space complexity?

Comment: This would be more efficient using a [deque](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.deque)